# How can i cancel an alarm after 10 seconds?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an issue here. I want to set an alarm and then stop it automatically after 10 seconds. I used the code below but it doesn't stop after 10 seconds.

Here's the setAlarm method of my activity:

```
public void setAlarm(int hour, int minute) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Set the alarm to start at "hour"
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    Intent i = new Intent(AccueilPA.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AccueilPA.this, 10, i, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            test = true;
        }
    }.start();
    // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
    if (alarmManager != null && test) {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The PendingIntent needs to be created exactly as it was when you start the AlarmManager.
You have set the pending intent request code as 10 while creating it. You have to use the same to cancel it.

**Create Alarm:**

```
    private void createalarm(int hour , int minute){

    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    Log.i("TestAlarm" , " Created Alarm");

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           cancelAlarm();
        }
    }.start();

}
```

**Cancel Alarm:**

```
    private void cancelAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Log.i("TestAlarm" , " Cancelled Alarm");
}
```

**BroadCast Receiver Class:**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("TestAlarm" , "Alarm Triggered!");
  }
}
```

Comment: I set the alarm and I cancel it in the same method, so there's one PendingIntent used in both create and cancel. I don't really get your answer.

Comment: You have to create Pending Intent again to cancel the existing one.

Comment: @Hasnaa Please accept the answer if it has helped you.